# Планировщик событий in Java

Tags: java, mysql, веб-программирование, hibernate, события

Я сейчас учу Web на Java и в качестве первого проекта делаю интернет аукцион. После написания всех CRUD - операций, перед мною стала задача - "как проверять окончание аукциона лота" и тут я застрял.

Собственно в "БД" у лота есть два поля: `startDate` и `finishDate` - моя идея в том чтобы после запуска приложения стартовал какой - то event schedule object, который брал дату окончания лота и проверял с актуальной датой, и в зависимости от этого менял состояние лота. Если кто - нибудь делал что - то нибудь подобное подскажите в какую сторону смотреть, чтобы приложение не тормозило в результате таких проверок или может у Вас есть ссылка, где эта проблема реализована.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить несколько вариантов:

1. Самый банальный, запустить фоновый поток, который будет проверять. Это можно сделать при помощи [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)
2. При помощи сторонней библиотеки [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
3. Если вы используете `spring` то есть вариант, воспользоваться аннотацией `@Scheduled`для выбора метода, который будет выполняться с заданной периодичностью
4. Рекомендую так же посмотреть такой проект, как [spring batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/), для пакетной обработки данных